# Be $n \in \mathbb N$ and $A \in Mat(n \times n, \mathbb C)$ with real entries and be $A^t = A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help with this task. I don't know what to do. A solution or help is greatly appreciate!

Be $n \in \mathbb N$ and $A \in Mat(n \times n, \mathbb C)$ with real entries and be $A^t = A$.

(i) Are all eigenvalues of $A$ real numbers?

(ii) Be $(v_{1},...,v_n),(w_{1},...,w_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ eigenvectors of $A$ regarding the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Suppose that $\lambda \neq \mu $. Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n v_iw_i = 0$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We have $A^* = (\bar A)^t = A^t = A$ and so $A$ is self-adjoint.

(i)
If $Av=\lambda v$ with $v \ne 0$, then
$$
\lambda \langle v,v \rangle
= \langle \lambda v,v \rangle
= \langle A v,v \rangle
= \langle v, A^* v \rangle
= \langle v, A v \rangle
= \langle v, \lambda v\rangle
= \bar\lambda \langle v,v \rangle
$$
implies $\lambda = \bar\lambda$ and so $\lambda$ is real.

(ii)
$$
\lambda \langle v,w \rangle
= \langle \lambda v,w \rangle
= \langle A v,w \rangle
= \langle v, A^* w \rangle
= \langle v, A w \rangle
= \langle v, \mu w\rangle
= \bar\mu \langle v,w \rangle
= \mu \langle v,w \rangle
$$
implies $\langle v,w \rangle=0$ since $\lambda \ne \mu$.